# Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined, when open it through Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, socket.io

When I open app through heroku it shows couple errors related with Socket.io. When I run it on localhost everything works just fine.

```
// server.js
const app = require('./app');
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

console.log(`Mode: ${process.env.NODE_ENV}`);
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port: ${port}`);
});
```

```
// index.html
script(src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
script(src='/js/bundle.js')
```

```
// script.js
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io();
```

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
jQuery.Deferred exception: io is not defined ReferenceError: io is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (https://infinite-meadow-83816.herokuapp.com/js/bundle.js:604:6379)
    at l (https://infinite-meadow-83816.herokuapp.com/js/bundle.js:535:29386)
    at c (https://infinite-meadow-83816.herokuapp.com/js/bundle.js:535:29688) undefined
Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (bundle.js:604)
    at l (bundle.js:535)
    at c (bundle.js:535)
DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: https://infinite-meadow-83816.herokuapp.com/bundle.js.map
```

[Image with errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1t5x.png)

Comment: Let's see your `package.json`, please?

Comment: Man, everything works fine now. I just realize that when I pushed new data to heroku I didn't commited it.